# OpenAI API: How do I handle errors in Python?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I tried using the below code, but the OpenAI API doesn't have the `AuthenticationError` method in the library. How can I effectively handle such error.

```
import openai

# Set up your OpenAI credentials
openai.api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

try:
    # Perform OpenAI API request
    response = openai.some_function()  # Replace with the appropriate OpenAI API function

    # Process the response
    # ...
except openai.AuthenticationError:
    # Handle the AuthenticationError
    print("Authentication error: Invalid API key or insufficient permissions.")
    # Perform any necessary actions, such as displaying an error message or exiting the program
```

Comment: do you make sure that your API_Key looks right and valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Error handling with the OpenAI Python SDK `v1.0.0` or newer

• If you *don't* want to handle error types individually:

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI, OpenAIError
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

try:
  # Make your OpenAI API request here
  response = client.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt="Say this is a test"
  )
  print(response)
except OpenAIError as e:
  # Handle all OpenAI API errors
  print(f"Error: {e}")
```

• If you want to handle error types individually:

*Note: Because there are a lot of classes for error handling, it might not be so elegant to import them individually. Instead, use `import openai` and all classes for error handling will be imported automatically. **But the code is a bit different now.***

```
import os
import openai # Import openai
from openai import OpenAI # But don't import OpenAIError
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

try:
  # Make your OpenAI API request here
  response = client.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt="Say this is a test"
  )
  print(response)
except openai.BadRequestError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error 400
  print(f"Error 400: {e}")
except openai.AuthenticationError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error 401
  print(f"Error 401: {e}")
except openai.PermissionDeniedError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error 403
  print(f"Error 403: {e}")
except openai.NotFoundError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error 404
  print(f"Error 404: {e}")
except openai.UnprocessableEntityError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error 422
  print(f"Error 422: {e}")
except openai.RateLimitError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error 429
  print(f"Error 429: {e}")
except openai.InternalServerError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle error >=500
  print(f"Error >=500: {e}")
except openai.APIConnectionError as e: # Don't forget to add openai
  # Handle API connection error
  print(f"API connection error: {e}")
```

See the official [OpenAI GitHub Python repository](https://github.com/openai/openai-python?tab=readme-ov-file#handling-errors).

### Error handling with the OpenAI Python SDK `v0.28.0`

**Your code isn't correct.**

Change this...

```
except openai.AuthenticationError
```

...to this.

```
except openai.error.AuthenticationError
```